# Retrieve random data from MySQL if empty look for next

Tags: mysql, random

I would like to retrieve random data from a column however skip if empty. I tried everything i found here but no luck

```
$sql = 'SELECT video FROM data ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1';
```

I also read that Order By Rand is slow when you have huge database, if true what is the alternative

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = 'SELECT video FROM data WHERE video !="" ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1';
```

Or now that I think about it, I really prefer:

```
$sql = 'SELECT video FROM data WHERE LENGTH(TRIM(video)) > 0 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1';
```

Comment: Can you explain if you want for my future ref, Thanks

Comment: Glad to help! What goes around comes around.